# Pascal - size of array

Tags: arrays, freepascal

I have code, in which I input each number on new line until I write 0. I am confused about size of array. In begining i declare that A is array with indices 1 to 5. But when I keep writing and put more than 5 numbers, it seems like it is still saved and then later used in second for cycle. How is that possible? I thought if i run out of indices I would get an error.

```
program testarray;
var hmez,                            
    i:integer;                           
    A:array [1..5] of integer;

begin
i:=0;
   repeat                                            
   inc(i);
   readln(A[i]); 
   if A[i]=0 then hmez:=i-1;
   until A[i]=0;
for i:=1 to hmez do
  writeln(A[i]);
end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting memory that doesn't belong to the `A` variable. This will sooner or later cause an unhandled exception (run-time error) or any other 'weird' behavior caused be the memory leak. Unlike from 'managed' languages such as C# or Java in Pascal run-time checking of array indices is an optional feature, not a mandatory, enforced, language feature.

Pascal compilers usually have an option to turn on or off array index checks which is called 'range checking'. The directive `{$R+}` turns on these range checks — see the [documentation here](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/prog/progsu65.html).

In your case the code seems to 'work' only because, likely, there's no other useful variable placed in the memory after the space allocated for `A`. Please note this is just a conincidence and may not be that case in all runs of your program. So generally, your program as-is is incorrect.

Comment: thank you, so you are suggesting to turn on range checks to make my program correct?

Comment: You should check if the index is valid in your code at the first place. Compiler-generated range checks are a safety net. However, yes, you should definitely have them turned on at all times.

Comment: Your program is incorrect in nature. Turning range checks on won't introduce correctness; it will let you know explicitly it's incorrect.

Comment: thank you once again, I actually increase the size via setlength function once the i>size of array.